# Maximum number of connected components of a real affine curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, real-algebraic-geometry

[Harnack's curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_curve_theorem) tells us that the maximum number of connected components of an algebraic curve of degree $d$ in the real projective plane is $1 + (d-1)(d-2)/2$ (and this bound is sharp).

What happens if "projective" is replaced by "affine"?  What is the maximum number of connected components then?

The only relevant reference I have been able to find so far is a paper by [Korchagin and Weinberg](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1181070130) on the isotopy classification of affine quartic curves, where they calculate that a compact affine quartic curve has no more than 4 connected components and a noncompact affine quartic curve has no more than 7 connected components.  I think their argument can be extended to higher degree to give an upper bound, but are these bounds sharp?

Comment: One possible strategy is to find hyperplanes of projective space cutting a given curve $C$ in as few components as possible (thus cutting those up into many pieces). I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: It seems the answer is here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68954/maximal-number-of-connected-components-of-complement-to-an-affine-plane-real-alg

Comment: @VladMatei : I saw that question before I posted my question but I don't see how it answers my question.

Comment: You are right it does not seem quite that. Let's try this on page 8: http://math.caltech.edu/~2014-15/3term/ma191c-sec2/2%20Basic%20real%20AG.pdf

Comment: @VladMatei : That argument gives an upper bound but still does not answer the question.